# Copy a specific range of data from one sheet to other

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to copy a specific range of data i.e. A7 till A10000 and C7 till C10000 of one sheet to A1 and B1
 cells of the other sheet. but I am not able to do that using the below

```
Sheets("Appointment").Columns("A7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Security Appt_Location").Range("A1")
Sheets("Appointment").Columns("C7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Security Appt_Location").Range("B1")
```

Can I define the range in the above sentences?

Answer (score 1):

`Columns("A7")` is an invalid specification. Columns are identifed by letter or index, e.g., `Columns("A")` or `Columns(1)`.

If you fix that, the code should work, barring some other circumstances like worksheet protection, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're only copying a single cell, and your code would benefit from a little reworking to reduce duplication:

```
  Dim sht
  Set sht = Sheets("Security Appt_Location")

  With Sheets("Appointment")
     .Range("A7:A10000").Copy Destination:=sht.Range("A1")
     .Range("C7:C10000").Copy Destination:=sht.Range("B1")
  End With
```

Comment: It is not working, I am trying to copy the datat to a different sheet and it os giving me a object defined error